# How can i extract bz2 file in Java on Android?

Tags: java, android, bz2

How can i extract bz2 file in Java on Android? Are any included libraries in android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My best bet would be to try [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/index.html). It has a built-in bzip2 (de)compressor: [example](http://commons.apache.org/compress/examples.html#bzip2). I'm not particularly sure though it will run on Android out of the box, but worth a try I'd say.

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at the [bzip2/libzip2 library compiled for Android](https://github.com/crystax/cosp-android-bzip2).

Comment: The second link is dead. There seems to be a copy [here](https://github.com/Intermodalics/cosp-android-bzip2) but it's older than your answer so I don't know which is the original...